# Счетчик нажатия на элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```css
body {
  background: aquamarine;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script>
$('body').on('click', function () {
  function makeCounter() {
    var currentCount = 1;
    return function (){
      return currentCount++;
    };   
  }
 
    var counter = makeCounter();

    alert(counter());
 })
</script>
</body>
```

Вопрос первый , почему не работает **алерт**, во вторых при новом клике не работает счетчик, выдает только **1**

Comment: А в чем возникли трудности?

Comment: В чем заключается ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Владимир Владимирович конкретно в вашем примере переменная currentCount  при каждом вызове makeCounter равна 1. Выносите её определение за функцию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var clk = 0;

$(document).on('click', function() {

    clk++;
    
    console.clear();
    console.log(clk);
    
});
```

```css
body {
  background: aquamarine;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо!как обычно помогли!

Comment: @ВладимирВладимирович разве вам не нужно было замыкание?

Comment: @ИгорьПоляков мне нужна была реализация счетчика , но спасибо за Ваш ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Новый `counter` создается на каждый клик. Вынесите его создание из обработчика:

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;
  return function() {
    return currentCount++;
  };
}
var counter = makeCounter();

$(document).on('click', function() {
  alert(counter());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Без внешних переменных:

```js
$(document).on('click', function() {
  var clickCount = +$(this).data("clickcount");
  if (!clickCount)
    clickCount = 1;

  alert(clickCount++);

  $(this).data("clickcount", clickCount)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

В описанном вами коде функция инициализируется и назначается в переменную каждый раз при клике на `body`. Поэтому она просто не может отсчитывать что-то больше 1.  Потому что всегда выполняется один и тот же код заново. Чтобы этого не было, вынесите функцию с замыканим наружу, а при клике уже вызывайте.

И еще у вас `body` не имел высоты, поэтому клик бы все равно не прошел. Для теста, поставьте `border` в CSS и увидите это сами. А с высотой будет так:

```js
function makeCounter() {
  var currentCount = 1;
  return function() {
    return currentCount++;
  };
}

var counter = makeCounter();


$("body").on("click", function() {
  console.log(counter());
});
```

```css
body {
  background: aquamarine;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: вы модифицировали код, в вопросе он не такой. и там есть другие причины чтобы в оригинале он не работал. так что body тут не при делах

Comment: @teran да вы правы. Я дописал. Хотя автору видимо это уже не нужно)

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется так проще

```js
var count = 0;
document.body.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
console.log(count++);
})
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: хороший счетсчик спасиб)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...))